# Solving $(x-1) \left(e^{2-x}-2\right) +1 < 0$

Tags: inequality

I would like to know if the following inequality can be solved (for $x$) without the usage of functions/monotony:

$$(x-1) \left(e^{2-x}-2\right) +1 < 0$$

Comment: the term is inequality.

Comment: Can you provide a bit more context here please? What techniques are you looking to use? And have you thought about the problem yourself? Showing your work here will help people see where you are coming from and give an answer that doesn't repeat things you have already tried

Comment: We solved this in class using the given function `f(x)=(e^(2-x))+((1)/(x-1))-3, x>1` and Monotony. Then we got a solution (x > 2 or x < 2 if I recall correctly).

I was wondering if this can be solved without any given functions.

I thought of using log to solve the ^x, but I'm not sure if that's correct.

Comment: If you are only looking at real functions, you cannot take the log of the left side because it is a strictly negative number

Comment: If $f(x)=(x-1) \left(e^{2-x}-2\right) +1$ we have $f(2)=0$ and for $x>2$ the inequality is true. There is another value around $x_1=0.55$ where $f(x)=0$ and for $x<x_1$ the inequality holds. But I used graph. No algebraic way to solve this kind of inequalities or equations

Comment: @Raffaele Is it possible to solve this without any function?

Comment: @Coto No way it's a trascendental equation